# PHP preg_match check for dynamic set of special characters?

Tags: php, preg-match

In an application i need to do a special character check for dynamic set of special characters that is taken from db.I have tried the following, but it doesnt work,any help will be appreciated.

```
$specialCharacters = SystemParameters::model()->findByAttributes(array('sys_param_name' => 'SPLCHR'));
// [\^Â£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+Â¬-]'"; This is the resulting value
$var = addslashes($specialCharacters->sys_param_val);

if (preg_match('/' . $var . '/', $string))
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-quote.php) to quote your special characters like this.

```
preg_match('/' . preg_quote($var, '/') . '/', $string)
```

Based on the fact, that your result from database is not enclosed with square brackets I suppose you want something like this to match against a single special character in your string:

```
preg_match('/[' . preg_quote($var, '/') . ']/', $string)
```